# How to avoid writing duplicate code in sql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure inside of which I have couple of if else statements half of which needs to execute the same large code chunk.

This large code chunk comprises of calling various inline TVF's using various parameters passed to the stored procedure.

Like below ,there are a couple more conditions when I need to execute this large code chunk. What structures can help me avoid this code repetition without much overhead or may be if it is possible to handle it with help of `if else` alone ?

All this code is inside of a stored procedure and calling inline TVF's uses some parameters and values calculated in stored procedure so I doubt if creating a function would help.

The sample flow is as follows:
[image]

Sample code is as follows : 
Note : If else statements may be a little messed up logically since this is where I am stuck

```
if exists(select * from dbo.ResultsStored where Hashedkey = HashBytes('MD5', @StringConcat))
begin

if exists(SELECT  * FROM    ResultsStored RS CROSS APPLY 
( SELECT    MAX(ModifiedAt) AS ModifiedAt FROM Patients pt  WHERE    pt.RowId = RS.RowId) p
WHERE   p.ModifiedAt > rs.ModifiedAt )
begin

print 'begin exists'
if @firstname is not null
begin
 SELECT @constVal = FunctionWeight FROM   dbo.FunctionWeights WHERE  FunctionWeights.FunctionId = 1;
 INSERT INTO #Temp2 (RowNumber,ValFromUser,ColumnName,ValFromFunc,FuncWeight,percentage) 
  SELECT RowNumber,@firstname,'firstname',PercentMatch,@constVal,PercentMatch * @constVal FROM   dbo.MatchFirstName(@firstname)
END 

 if @Middlename is not null
  BEGIN
      SELECT @constVal = FunctionWeight FROM   dbo.FunctionWeights WHERE  FunctionWeights.FunctionId = 2;
  INSERT INTO #Temp2 (RowNumber,ValFromUser,ColumnName,ValFromFunc,FuncWeight,percentage)
      SELECT RowNumber, @MiddleName,'Middlename',PercentMatch, @constVal,PercentMatch * @constVal FROM   dbo.MatchMiddleName(@MiddleName)
END 


   /* and calling goes on */  --until this is the large piece of code that needs to be repeated
select * from #Temp2
print 'updating results table'
Update dbo.ResultsStored set FinalSearchSeral = @searchNumber,  ModifiedAt = getDate(), PercentMatch  =  t.Perc from (select SUM(Percentage)/@cnt as Perc from #Temp2 GROUP BY RowNumber ) t  where HashedKey = HASHBYTES('MD5', @StringConcat)
select * from dbo.ResultsStored where Hashedkey = HashBytes('MD5', @StringConcat) order by SearchSerial desc, PercentMatch desc
end

 else if exists(select * from dbo.ResultsStored join dbo.Patients on Patients.rowId = ResultsStored.rowId where ResultsStored.Hashedkey = HashBytes('MD5', @StringConcat) and Patients.ModifiedAt <= ResultsStored.ModifiedAt  )
 begin
 print 'select only'
 select * from dbo.ResultsStored where HashedKey = HASHBYTES('MD5', @StringConcat) order by SearchSerial desc, PercentMatch desc
 end
 end
 else if not exists(select * from dbo.ResultsStored where Hashedkey = HashBytes('MD5', @StringConcat))
begin
print 'insert record';
select * from #Temp2
Insert into dbo.ResultsStored( searchSerial,FinalSearchSeral, StringSearched, RowId,PercentMatch, HashedKey) 
select @searchNumber, @searchNumber, dbo.encrypt(@StringConcat), RowNumber, (SUM(Percentage)/@cnt) as Percentage , HASHBYTES('MD5', @StringConcat)
FROM #Temp2 GROUP BY RowNumber 
select * from dbo.ResultsStored 
end
```

Comment: One "solution" is to use nested stored procs. But realistically the real problem is having business logic in SQL. Even though SQL is strictly a Turing Complete language, it does not make for a good language to put any real logic into. Also, a quick cursary glance at the code suggests that you are trying to build a Full Text Search index in SQL (aka a Relational DataBase Management System), as opposed to a Relational Database in an RDBMS. Consider using a Full Text Search for Full Text Search.

Comment: it is something like what is better linux or windows. There a lot of people who says that business logic in SQL is good idea and a lot of other who says that it is not.

Comment: @sidux, erm no...fact is that SQL lacks very basic features required for serious code reusage, passing of array like objects into functions...I honestly haven't met anyone who has seriously suggested Sprocs were the way forward in the last 5 years.

Comment: @Aron : I could not use Full Text search for the reason that it does not allow variable prefix checks

Comment: @Simran What do you mean by "prefix checking"? Why does it seem like a good solution to reinvent the wheel instead of customizing it for your needs?

Comment: As I said that it is something like windows vs linux. We have a lot of applications with the logic built on the SQL server and for the bigest amount of the logic it is working very well.

Comment: By variable prefix checks, this is what I mean. For word Hello , I needed to check percentage match with ellora, Since Hello starts with H and ellora with e, full text search would not see the match. However, I needed to check number of matched chars with unmatched chars. so in hello with ellora, match - 4 (because of ello) and unmtach = 3 (because of hra)

Comment: @Aron:Creating another stored procedure can not help in this case as I am creating a temporary table in that code and that temp table would not be accessible in outer sp then.

Comment: @Simran that is exactly the pain point I am referring to. Honestly, Sprocs are your problem here. But again, you will find almost impossibly bad perf the way you are going. A traditional RDBMS cannot index the search terms you are creating. What you are looking for is called Proximity Search. This is a feature of many Full Text Search engine, consider using something like Apache Solr.

Comment: Thank you @Aron . I will definitely look into that.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is the same then you can write something like that

```
IF (Time > Y OR @ColumnA = @X) BEGIN ... END
```

In your example you can do something like:

```
IF (@firstname IS NOT NULL) BEGIN SET @name = @firstname; SET @fId = 1;  END;
    IF (@Middlename IS NOT NULL) BEGIN SET @name = @Middlename; SET @fId =2;  END;
    IF (
        IF EXISTS ( SELECT
                        *
                    FROM
                        ResultsStored RS
                        CROSS APPLY (
                                      SELECT
                                        MAX(ModifiedAt) AS ModifiedAt
                                      FROM
                                        Patients pt
                                      WHERE
                                        pt.RowId = RS.RowId
                                    ) p
                    WHERE
                        p.ModifiedAt > RS.ModifiedAt )

                        SELECT
                            @constVal = FunctionWeight
                        FROM
                            dbo.FunctionWeights
                        WHERE
                            FunctionWeights.FunctionId = @fId;
                        INSERT  INTO #Temp2
                                ( RowNumber ,
                                  ValFromUser ,
                                  ColumnName ,
                                  ValFromFunc ,
                                  FuncWeight ,
                                  percentage
                                )
                                SELECT
                                    RowNumber ,
                                    @firstname ,
                                    'firstname' ,
                                    PercentMatch ,
                                    @constVal ,
                                    PercentMatch * @constVal
                                FROM
                                    dbo.MatchFirstName(@name)
```

Comment: Could you please explain how does this solve my issue? I feel a bit lost myself .